# Upload file in a location specified in tomcat server.xml conf

Tags: java, file, tomcat, spring-mvc, upload

I have an upload form and I would like to save the file in my filesystem.

First, I tried to create the path where the uploaded file will be saved:

```
File dest = new File("/front/uploads/images");
dest.mkdirs();
```

I specified a context to "front/uploads" in my tomcat server.xml conf

```
<Context path="/front/uploads" docBase="${htdocs}/uploads" reloadable="false" />
```

But the mkdirs fails everytime.

What I did wrong ?

Thanks

PS: I simplified a bit

Comment: How does it fail? Exception, returns false?

Comment: it return false. I even tried to give all access 777 to the folder ${htdocs}/uploads

Comment: I want to create the folders from my applications.
If I remove the first slash, the folders tree is created in my tomcat root directory.

Comment: Not really, I just want to upload a specific type of file in a specific generated folder tree. That why I want to create the folders if it isnt exist.

Comment: Yes, the folder can change very often. it will be something like "u8/02/fy"...That why I cant create them manually. I just simplified too much maybe :p

Comment: You must have some other permission problems because it works fine for me.

Comment: Does your folder is created in ${htdocs}/uploads/images" ?

Comment: No, I just called the 2 lines you have above. Not doing it through tomcat.

Comment: oh, yes, I think it should works too. But the problem may be when I want to save the file in a folder specified in tomcat conf.

Comment: If it is a valid folder name, it should still work. Maybe cleanup your question so we know exactly what you are looking for.